# Is it possible to hack a database inside of local network by external attacker?

Tags: network, databases, attack-prevention, server, router

Can an attacker from global network hack a database located on office machine inside of local office network? For example after hacking a router, a gateway or the very machine? Or maybe there is another way for him? Is it possible to make local network with database absolutely secure? Maybe to turn the database on just when it's needed and turn off the connection to global network at such time?

Comment: While it might certainly possible to combine several attacks to hack the database, if this can be done and how it can be done depend on detailed knowledge of your exact environment - which is unknown. Similar it is impossible to say how to best secure the database in your unknown environment. Note though that attacks to the database might not even be done directly, but might be done through an application accessing the database which is vulnerable to SQL injection or similar.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'absolutely secure'. What's considered sufficiently secure today, might be different tomorrow or next week. On an infrastructure level, as a start, do not expose the database port to the entire internal network, only allow hosts that are required to communicate with with the database server.

Answer (score 2):

If there was a standard, easily answerable way to make a local network "absolutely secure", most of the community here would not have jobs. It's not nearly that simple. Network security is incredibly complex. And the environment, the people using it, and the people attacking it are constantly changing, adapting, and evolving.

> Can an attacker from global network hack a ... machine inside of local office network?

Of course. This happens all the time.

> maybe there is another way...?

The answer to that is "how many paths *could* there be?" The more direct route is to infect the machine's administrator's PC with malware and use that to access the machine. That's just one "hop" to the target. But one could use whatever means necessary to create one's own "network" to reach the target. And this happens all the time, too.

> turn the database on just when it's needed

This is a form of "air gapping" and this, in a crude way, implements a security principle that things should only be accessible when they are needed. But the costs and inconvenience tend to be very high for this approach, and it is still vulnerable once it turns on.

If you are looking for an approach to start designing security for this machine, there are multiple frameworks that you can use as a guide. At a high level, and broadly applicable, the [NIST CSF](https://www.nist.gov/cyberframework) provides practical, actionable factors to consider. But nothing will make it "absolutely secure". You only increase the chances for the machine to remain in a secure state.

Comment: Ok. So, as I can understand, the only absolutely secure (but more expensive and limited) approach is the following "air gap". Each employee of a company has two devices on his desk: the first one is connected to the local network which in turn is connected to the Internet and the second one is connected to a separate local network (including the database server) which is not connected to the global network at all and never. At that such two devices are not connected one another. It's absolutely secure, but limited approach that can be used only for internal needs of the company. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit "wide". The attack that you described is plausible. Of course and as you said there might be different ways of accessing:

- Deprecated software with available exploits exposed to the internet could open a door to attackers
- Phishing attacks could be another vector of attack

It is hard to explain all the different alternatives that an attacker could take and if I were asked to provide the highest security level towards protecting the database server I would probably suggest an air gap that would phisically separate any exposed service from the DB itself. Of course this is not always possible and every different scenario would require some analysis.